# pausar página e retomar após confirmação do usuário

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Galera tenho a seguinte estrutura em php:

```
            <?php
            // Verifica se cancela o cadastro
            if ((!empty($action)) and ($action == "cancelar")) {

                ?>
                <script>
                    confirm ('Tem certeza que quer cancelar?>');
                </script>
                <?php
                die;

                // Aqui executa as operaçøes no BD
            }
        ?>
```

Bom preciso de fazer o php processar as informações do usuário apenas se o usuário confirmar o alert.

Tem como fazer isso usando jQuery?

Comment: Tem de fazer com ajax, ou crie um cookie (com valor true/false) com javascript e depois redirecione/reload da página. Consegue ver o valor do cookie no php: `$_COOKIE['NOME DO COOKIE']`

Comment: Seria melhor você colocar esse confirm() no onClick do botão de cancelamento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso direto no link de cancelar:

```
<a title="Cancelar" onclick="return confirm('Você tem certeza?');" href="seuscript.php?ation=cancelar&id=XX">Cancelar</a>
```

Mas se você quer realmente fazer com php segue um exemplo:

```
<?php

    $action = $_GET['action'];
    // Verifica se cancela o cadastro
    if ((!empty($action)) and ($action == "cancelar")) {  ?>
        <a title="Cancelar" href="seuscript.php?action=cancelar-confirmado&id=XX">VocÊ tem certeza que deseja cancelar?</a>
    <?php
    }elseif ((!empty($action)) and ($action == "cancelar-confirmado")){
        # seu codigo de cancelamento aqui
        echo "Cancelado com sucesso!!";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Só por que o JS esta "dentro" do PHP não significa que o `confirm()` vá impedir a execução do PHP, até por que, de maneira geral, quando exibir o `confirm()` o PHP já terminou de executar.

Outro detalhe é que o `confirm()` [como mostra a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) retorna `true` ou `false` por isso precisa verificar a resposta com um `if`.

Sem mais detalhes complica de dar um exemplo melhor mais o correto seria algo desse tipo:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var btCancela = document.getElementById('cancelar');
  btCancela.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if( confirm('Deseja realmente cancelar?') ){
      //aqui é o pulo do gato, você precisar fazer uma requisição ajax ou redirecionar para uma outra URL, ou seja la como você apaga o registro do banco.
      console.log('usuario confirmou o cancelamento');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="cancelar">CANCELAR</a>
```

Javascript e PHP são linguagens diferentes para propósitos diferentes, infelizmente não se comunicam da forma que você imaginou.